# Proper filtering of table which contains multiple records within the same account

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I need to join table "customer" and table "comment".
I want to find out the account created on 3/24/2021 from "customer" table. Subsequently, filtering those accounts that doesn't has the "dormant" word in the "comment_desc" column of the "comment" table.
Refer to my SQL, Tables and expected result:

```
My SQL:
Select customer.account, customer.creation_date, customer.country 
From DATABASE.customer, DATABASE.comment
Where customer.account=comment.account
And customer.creation_date = '03/24/2021'
And comment.comment_desc not like '%Dormant%'

Table 1: Customer
account | creation_date | country
1111111 | 24/3/2021     | AU
2222222 | 25/3/2021     | NZ
3333333 | 24/3/2021     | AU
4444444 | 24/3/2021     | AU
5555555 | 24/3/2021     | NZ

Table 2: Comment
account | comment_date  | comment_desc
1111111 | 24/3/2021     | newly created
1111111 | 24/3/2021     | callback
1111111 | 25/3/2021     | Update rate
1111111 | 25/3/2021     | Sales follow up
2222222 | 25/3/2021     | newly created
2222222 | 25/3/2021     | Sales follow up
2222222 | 25/3/2021     | Update rate
3333333 | 24/3/2021     | callback
3333333 | 25/3/2021     | manual Dormant
4444444 | 24/3/2021     | Update rate
4444444 | 24/3/2021     | Update account info
4444444 | 24/3/2021     | Sales follow up
5555555 | 24/3/2021     | Update rate
5555555 | 24/3/2021     | Dormant entry

Expected Result:
account  | creation_date | country
1111111  | 24/3/2021     | AU
4444444  | 24/3/2021     | AU
```

Please kindly assist to advice how I should revise/improve my SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from customer
where creation_date = '03/24/2021'
  and account not in (
    select account from comment where comment_desc like '%Dormant%'
  )
```